# enumerate with itemsep newpage and variable page heights

Tags: lists, enumitem

I would like to have a macro that sets each enumi level item from an enumeration list such that:

1. it appears on its own page and
2. the page is cropped to just that text

Hence the resulting pdf will have variable page heights (if that is possible in latex (if that is possible in pdf even)).

I tried with the `enumitem` package but wasn't able to even get each enumi onto one page alone, for which my ME is given below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[itemsep={\newpage}]
    \item This line should be on a page on its own the page height being just large enough to contain it.
    \item This line also would like to be on a page on its own and the height of its page would also be just large enough to contain it.
    \item Once again, same as above
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

CONTEXT: While using Microsoft's oneNote, one can insert a print out of a pdf into a notebook. This appears to convert each page of the pdf into a separate image. Hence the initial presentation in the notebook is the list as it is, yet it is very easy for a student to create space themselves between the items. The idea I have is that the lists are exercises. The students can organise themselves the space they need to solve the exercise.

Comment: You can use `itemsep={\textheight}` to force every item on a new page. Shortening the page is more difficult.

Comment: Does difficult mean impossible? I suppose that one could add a \hrule as an itemsep and then use an external script to crop there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are willing to add a command at the end of an item you could try something like this. 
(The main problem is that zsavepos gives the position from the bottom of the file, so it changes if you shorten the page).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\newcounter{myitem}
\newcommand\meti{%end of item
 \stepcounter{myitem}\zsavepos{item-\number\value{myitem}}%
 \pdfpageheight=\dimexpr \zposy{top-\number\value{myitem}}sp-\zposy{item-\number\value{myitem}}sp+2cm\relax\newpage}

\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{\AtPageUpperLeft{\zsavepos{top-\number\value{myitem}}}}

\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=\textheight]
    \item This line should be on a page on its own the page height being just large enough to contain it.\meti
    \item This line also would like to be on a page on its own and the height of its page would also be just large enough to contain it.\meti
    \item Once again, same as above. \meti
    \item \lipsum*[1]\meti
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. I have played with your code. Is it necessary for the \AddToShipoutPictureFG to be the first line or can it be in the preamble? (I tested it and it seemed to work.)

Comment: Preamble should work too, I think I had it in the document because I thought at first only one label on the first page would be enough.